# In Github, I'm getting an error that a file is too big when pushing, who do I remove it?

Tags: github

I have some files that are too big for github and I'm getting an error. I don't really need the file so I just removed the file. However, I've already committed (not pushed) so the file is already in the commit and being treated like it exists. I've tried doing a hard reset as well as `git add -u` but it doesn't do anything helpful.

I need to removed from my commit the items I deleted from the repo.

Comment: Did you try to [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the commit,  or [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) locally before pushing?

Comment: Do you have other commits this file is present in? If so, how many? (If you want to take it out from a large number of commits, that's one of the use cases `git filter-branch` is made for).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a good use for rebase.  From your repo directory, run

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

This will give you a list of the last few commits in your chosen editor, simply delete the line containing the problem commit and save, then follow the prompts for commit messages.

That should effectively roll back your local clone of the repo to before you committed the problem file and allow you to re-commit any changes you want to keep.

Comment: I removed the lines but I'm not sure who to put the change into effect

Comment: once you save and complete the next step (commit message) your local copy of the repository is changed